# Pulling data from mysql database into textarea

Tags: php, mysql, html

How can I edit this line of code so that it can pull data from the MySQL database into HTML 5 form for editing

```
<td width="276">
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="reasons" value="<?php echo $rsns;?>" placeholder="E.g. To pursue further studies" /></textarea>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

for textarea

```
<textarea><?php echo .. ;?></textarea>
```

so change

```
<td width="276"><textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="reasons" value="<?php echo $rsns;?>" placeholder="E.g. To pursue further studies" /></textarea></td>
```

to

```
<td width="276"><textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="reasons"  placeholder="E.g. To pursue further studies"><?php echo $rsns;?></textarea></td>
```